# Encrypting user information PHP

Tags: php, encryption

I have a simple txt file UserInfo.txt on a linux web server that simply has the username on one line and the password on the next line.  I know this is not secure at all.  The text file looks like below:

```
JohnDoe
JDPassword
```

I then have a PHP file that reads the UserInfo.txt file and uses that to authenticate against another web app.  I would like to encrypt this information so that it passes securely.

Here is the PHP function that reads the file and captures the username and password:

```
    function getCredentials($path = '../UserInfo.txt') {
    $credentials = null;
    try {
        if ($fh = fopen($path, 'r')) {
            $credentials = (object)array(
                "userName" => trim(fgets($fh)),
                "password" => trim(fgets($fh)),
                "keepAlive" => false
            );
        }
    } catch (Exception $ignored) {

    }
    return $credentials;
}
```

Looking for thoughts on how to easily change this current methodology to make it encrypted and more secure?

Comment: I mean, if you're concerned about the transport layer then SSL certificates give you TLS. If you want to implement symmetric/asymmetric encrypt then there is plenty of tools online to do this. What have you tried so far? Encryption here is done in the TLS, you should use own encryption to confirm the integrity of the sent data and to protect it locally.

Comment: What my concern is, if I go to https://www.example.com/UserInfo.txt, I see the contents of that file.  I want that file to be encrypted so it can't be read, but my PHP script can still read it.  If I use Notepadd++ to encrypt the file, then upload it to the server, that would encrypt it, but will my PHP file still be able to read it as it should?

Comment: Do not have it public facing then, require authorisation to access it via oAuth 2.0 for example?

Comment: Just don't store that file in the document root of your webserver. If you encrypt the file you have just shifted the problem: you'd have to store the encryption key securely. You really should have only one PHP file in the document root; a simple index.php that does nothing but include the actual app which is installed elsewhere.

Comment: Appreciate all of the responses.  Thank-you all, this has helped give me some better direction on what I need to do - thank-you!